# Why does Angular insist on custom prefixes for components?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I refer to https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#02-07 and the linter's insistance on a `kebab-case` selector.

What I want to have in `app.component.html` is:

```
<header aria-label="some useful text"></header>
<article class="loading" *ngIf="loading" id="main_content" aria-label="main">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</article>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!loading"  aria-label="routing tag"></router-outlet>
<footer aria-label="other useful text"></footer>
```

.... with my header & footer fragments defined in respective components

What, instead, I have to do is have:

```
<myapp-header aria-label="heading"></myapp-header>
<article class="loading" *ngIf="loading" id="main_content" aria-label="main">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</article>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!loading"  aria-label="routing tag"></router-outlet>
<myapp-footer aria-label="footing"></myapp-footer>
```

... and then have the actual `<header aria...>....</header>` and `<footer aria...>...</footer>` defined within their respective components.

This gives me a sub-optimal accessibility tree - with `text container` elements containing the `landmark` elements:

```
<myapp-header _ngcontent-jeq-c37="" aria-label="heading" _nghost-jeq-c35="">
  <header _ngcontent-jeq-c35="" aria-label="Header area" class="site-header side-padding">
    <a _ngcontent-jeq-c35="" href="#main_content" class="skip-link">Skip to content</a>
    <h1 _ngcontent-jeq-c35="" class="sr-only">My App Heading</h1>
    <nav _ngcontent-jeq-c35="" aria-label="Main navigation">
      ...
    </nav>
  </header>
</myapp-header>
<router-outlet _ngcontent-jeq-c37="" aria-label="routing tag" class="ng-star-inserted"></router-outlet>
<ng-component _nghost-jeq-c46="" class="ng-star-inserted">
// component
<myapp-footer _ngcontent-jeq-c37="" aria-label="footing" _nghost-jeq-c36="">
  <footer _ngcontent-jeq-c36="" role="contentinfo" aria-label="Footer area" class="side-padding">
    ...
  </footer>
</myapp-footer>
```

Why can't I have a nice sensible `<header>` and `<footer>`, and make them selectors?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: You seem to have confusion regarding many different topics.  I suggest you start by studying what a component actually is.

Answer (score 3):

Angular does not insist on the prefixes but suggest its usage. They explain it in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-selectors) with "*...it keeps the element names consistent with the specification for [Custom Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/)*".

If you want to get rid of the prefixes just remove them manually from the `selector` property used in the configuration object that is passed into the `@Component` decorator function.

Alternatively, in the `angular.json` file, set `prefix` to an empty string like so:

```json
"prefix": ""
```

Now when you generate a new component using the Angular CLI no prefix will be applied.

If you use a linter in your IDE that complains about it there should be a way to disable the warnings.